# How to match CSS LI and set widths

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to match `li` items based on the parent `ul`'s class in order to set the widths of the `li`s (inline-block).

Here is the corresponding code. I think the three `li`s should match ... and be 33% wide...

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    BODY {
      text-align: center;
    }
    DIV.listing_wrap {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    DIV.listing_wrap UL {
      border: 1px solid orange;
    }

    DIV.listing_wrap UL LI {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    DIV.listing_wrap UL.3col LI {
      width: 33%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="listing_wrap">
  <ul class="3col">
    <li class="t">1
    </li>
    <li class="t">2
    </li>
    <li class="r t">3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need so many classes, however you could match the `li`s with:

```
ul.listing_wrap li {
   width:33%;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, yes I'm aware of this, but the above sample is taken out of a bigger picture, so the classes are more defined.

Comment: As pointed by others, 3col is not a valid name for a class. However if you can't rewrite a CSS rule, try using `!important` after the rule

Answer (score 0):

Class identifiers should not start with a digit. For the test, set "col3" instead of "3col" and you will see it work !

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the layout as it had a width definition under DIV.listing_wrap UL LI, and this class is getting matched, so the LIs were infact the correct width. Can you take a look again, thanks...

Comment: Let me point out again, that the above example is taken out of bigger picture, and I would like to set widths of the LI elements via different UL classes....

Comment: With your edited code, I can reproduce it. I edited my answer. I currently cannot find a source on W3C stating that "class" attribute should not start with a digit. It is clear for "id" and "name" on http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata

Answer (score 0):

`ul.3col > li` will match any `li` that is directly a sibling of a `ul` with the class `.3col`

However, if you user a `%` width you should make sure the element actually has a parent to which it can relate for the actual px the % represents, else the results can be unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler your selectors are, the better. So this would be enough:

```
li { width: some other with for not 3 columns style}
.3col > li { width:33% }
```

also `3col` is not a valid classname.

Answer (score 0):

Or use table-cells... then you don't have to worry about width's:

```
.container { display: table; }
.container ul { display: table-row; }
.container ul li { display: table-cell; }
```